# How to make Heroku recoginize file that is hidden by gitignore?

Tags: git, heroku, github

So I'm developing a Flask app and use Heroku as my server. It works fine until I put my app_secret, app_id and some other sensitive info into a file (config.py) and use gitignore to hide it. Now even Heroku couldn't find it. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitignore files are entirely ignored from your GIT repository by design.
They remain only on your own machine, and are never sent to the repository.

Therefore, Heroku cannot get them.
You need to regenerate those files on your instance, or even better, use [configuration variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).